# How to solve an error 'cb is not a function' in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native

**current code**

Index.js

```js
import Auth from 'app/src/common/Auth';

export default class Index extends React.Component {

async componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus',
      Auth.me().then(async (response) => {
        await this.setState({ isLoggedIn: response });
      }));
}

...
}
```

Auth.js

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import { ENV } from 'app/env';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

const { baseApiUrl } = ENV;

export default {
  async me() {
    try {
      let result = false;
      let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
      token = token.replace(/"/g, '');
      const response = await axios.get(`${baseApiUrl}/api/auth/me`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      });
      if (response.data) {
        result = true;
      }
      return result;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  },

};
```

---

**error**

I keep getting this error.

> TypeError: cb is not a function. (In 'cb(data)', 'cb' is an instance of Promise)

I would appreciate it if you could give me any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its hard to tell without detail knowledge of your code (or react), but from the name i would expect `this.props.navigation.addListener` to take a `callback` function. Instead you pass a promise.

```
this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus',
  Auth.me().then(async (response) => {
    await this.setState({ isLoggedIn: response });
  })
);
```

Try changing the code to:

```
this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', () => {
  Auth.me().then(async (response) => {
    await this.setState({ isLoggedIn: response });
  })
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Seems like I need to know more about ```callback``` :( Anyway, thank you for advising.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: @kai answer is better (and correct) for the current problem. I will leave the answer though, using async/await on the setState function is wrong anyway

You should remove the `await` from setState:

```js
this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus',
  Auth.me()
    .then((response) => {
      this.setState({ isLoggedIn: response });
    })
);
```

By using `await`, Javascript expects a Promise. But `this.setState` does not return a function.

---

On a sidenote, if you need to await for a setState function to be applied, you could use the callback as second parameter:

```js
this.setState({ data }, () => console.log("Now the new state has been applied!"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I removed ```await``` from ```setState```.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same error by removing the listener from componentDidMount method

```
//this.props.navigation.addListener('focus', this._onFocus);
```